How can there be orla wine?
Bava Batra 24a, in the context of the majority vs proximity debate:

barrel of wine that was found hidden in a vineyard where there were orla grapes, and he was not concerned that the wine might be from the grapes of that vineyard (because majority trumps proximity...)

Why would one go to the trouble of making wine from orla grapes?
Since they are forbidden to benefit, making them into wine is a waste of effort.
Thus a more natural resolution of the question is "there is no such thing is orla wine".

Maybe the owner wasn't so frum and wanted to sell it as kosher

@DoubleAA: this suggests such a colossal laxity in observance that I feel forced to request a reference supporting such a possibility. TIA

@sds I admire your attitude, you are a true heir of  Rabbi Levi Yitzhak of Berdichev, Defender of Israel! Nevertheless, the Mishnah and Gamarra are full of examples of individuals who make a living dealing in orlah and shmittah year produce.

Maybe the owner didn't realize it was orla, and was only informed after he turned the grapes into wine
